# Making a Database Online

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am so confused with this issue,  I have vb.net application and it has a sql database .

Now, I want this application to access the sql server from anywhere , because there are many clients sharing the same database from many regions.

I don't want to make my current sql server available online by opening ports and allowing TCP remote connections, I am looking for a hosting service or solution that provides sql server database hosting. 
I just found web hosting services, and they do not allow users to use thier sql databases remotely for storage purposes.

Another words, I want to access it anywhere by some IP or domain or shared server, not by letting my computer working 24 hours to serve clients connections.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your requirement of having a database accessible from many remote locations is not uncommon.

If I were to do this, I would build a Windows Communication Framework (WCF) service that provides access to the database indirectly.  The WCF Service typically resides on a web server, where it operates as a proxy for the SQL Server.  The WCF service could provide security for the database by various authentication mechanisms; that is beyond the scope of this answer.

For information on WCF, check these documents:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42643/Creating-and-Consuming-Your-First-WCF-Service

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Create-a-WCF-Service-c3486993

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like cloud offerings fit the bill for your desired requirements.  I would recommend that you take a look at Microsoft Azure and what it can do for your.  Here are a few resources to get started with:

[SQL Database](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/sql-database/)
[Provisioning a SQL Server Virtual Machine on Azure](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-provision-sql-server/)

Those above options are two different things.  The first (SQL Database) is a service that renders a SQL database for you, while the second (Azure VM with SQL Server installed) is just that:  A virtual machine that has the SQL Server product installed.

[Here is a good reference on the differences between those two, which can help in making a decision and understanding the underlying specifics of each](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj879332.aspx).

*Disclaimer: I work for Microsoft*

Comment: Thanks man, but as I read today,  Windows Azure sql database has many limitations .. for example : No backup and restore,  No mirroring ... I think it's important things.

Comment: @AymAnAbuOmar I'm pretty sure you can backup and restore a database in Azure...where did you read that this was not possible?

Comment: Look at this : http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/ff394115.aspx